# Show that $B_n = \{x \in X : |\{j \in \mathbb{N} : x\in A_j\}| \geq n \}$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\{A_j\} \subseteq \Sigma$ be a countable family of measurable sets. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define
$$B_n = \{x \in X : |\{j \in \mathbb{N} : x\in A_j\}| \geq n \},$$
so $B_n$ is the set of points in $X$ in at least $n$ of the $A_j$s. Show that $B_n \in \Sigma$.

I think that this boils down to showing that you can construct $B_n$ via complements, countable unions, or countable intersections of the $A_j$s, but I cannot seem to get an angle on it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. After looking back at the context in which the problem was asked, I think the intention was for me to solve it via defining the measurable function $f(x) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty 1_{A_j}(x)$ (point-wise limit of simple functions) and re-characterize $B_n$. As shown in the accepted answer, this turns $B_n$ into the preimage of $[n, \infty)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x):=\sum_{_{j\ge 1}}1_{A_j}(x)$. Since $f$ (from $X$ to $[0,\infty]$) is a measurable function,
$$
B_n=\{x:f(x)\ge n\}\in \Sigma.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$B_n = \cup_{k_1 \ge 1} \cup_{k_2 \ge 1, k_2 \ne k_1} \cup_{k_3 \ge 1, k_3 \ne k_1, k_3 \ne k_2} \ldots \cup_{k_n \ge 1, k_n \ne k_j, 1 \le j \le n-1} A_{k_1} \cap A_{k_2} \cap \ldots \cap  A_{k_n}.$$

As $\cup_{k_n \ge 1, k_n \ne k_j, 1 \le j \le n-1} A_{k_1} \cap A_{k_2} \cap \ldots \cap  A_{k_n}$ is a countable union than it is an element of $\Sigma$. Similarly $B_n$ is an element of $\Sigma$.